# Método read() de System.in Java

Tags: java

desearía poder almacenar los bytes leídos de la entrada estándar (teclado por defecto) a partir de la posición 5º del array buffer_relleno. Para ello hice el siguiente código:

```
package ejercicio_1_2;

import java.io.*;

public class Ejercicio_1_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Introduce diez caracteres..");
        byte [] buffer_relleno = new byte[10]; // Creamos un array de maximo 10 posiciones
        int contador_bytes = System.in.read(buffer_relleno,4,5); // La variable contador_bytes almacena el numero de Bytes leidos
        int i = 0; // variable de iteracion
        while((i < 10) && (buffer_relleno[i] != 10)){ // buffer[i] diferente a diez porque no queremos imprimir la tecla ENTER, que en ASCII es 10.
            System.out.println("Has introducido: " + buffer_relleno[i] + "\n");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("El numero de bytes leidos es: " + (contador_bytes-1)); // contador-1 porque se tiene en cuenta la tecla ENTER del final
    }
}
```

Pero la salida que obtengo es la siguiente, en la que no entiendo varias cosas:

- por qué los carácteres A,B,C,D,J los toma como cero
- El número de bytes leídos no me cuadra, debería ser 6

Introduce diez caracteres..

ABCDEFGHIJ

Has introducido: 0

Has introducido: 0

Has introducido: 0

Has introducido: 0

Has introducido: 65

Has introducido: 66

Has introducido: 67

Has introducido: 68

Has introducido: 69

Has introducido: 0

El numero de bytes leidos es: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> por qué los carácteres A,B,C,D,J los toma como cero

Los primeros 4 no los toma como cero. A causa del `offset = 4` el primer caracter leído `A` se guarda  en la posición 4, el segundo `B` en la posición 5 y así hasta leer los 5 caracteres especificados en `len = 5`.

> El número de bytes leídos no me cuadra, debería ser 6

`len = 5`

Al ingresar los caracteres:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J
```

Leyendo con `offset = 4` y `len = 5`, el arreglo `buffer_relleno` queda así:

```
[ ,  ,  ,  , A, B, C, D, E,  ]
```

Comment: Entonces me surgen dos dudas: 1.Por qué imprime los valores de A,B,C,D,E si deberia imprimir E,F,G,H,I en código ASCII? Y supongo que debería ponerle len = 6 y el número de bytes leídos no sería contador_bytes - 1, sino contador_bytes, o me equivoco?

Comment: Es cierto, me había confundido con el `offset`.  Ya actualicé la respuesta.